# Does Scrapy allow us to scrape data from a server using JavaScript scripts?

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy

in my college the webpage we retrieve our semester results by typing the name and the student ID.
I am learning web scraping right now for projects, does scrapy or BeatifulSoup provide a solution for retrieving for example 100 results at one go?
you can view it's content here : view-source:http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp
it uses a code such as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-eg">
    <title></title>

<link href="natiga.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
<meta name="generator" content="Hassan_kandeell@yahoo.com" />
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var EW_DATE_SEPARATOR; // Default date separator
EW_DATE_SEPARATOR = "/";
if (EW_DATE_SEPARATOR == '') EW_DATE_SEPARATOR = '/';
EW_UPLOAD_ALLOWED_FILE_EXT = "gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,xls,pdf,zip"; // Allowed upload file extension
var EW_FIELD_SEP = ', '; // Default field separator
// Ajax settings
EW_LOOKUP_FILE_NAME = "ewlookup61.asp"; // lookup file name
EW_ADD_OPTION_FILE_NAME = "ewaddopt61.asp"; // add option file name
// Auto suggest settings
var EW_AST_SELECT_LIST_ITEM = 0;
var EW_AST_TEXT_BOX_ID;
var EW_AST_CANCEL_SUBMIT;
var EW_AST_OLD_TEXT_BOX_VALUE = "";
var EW_AST_MAX_NEW_VALUE_LENGTH = 5; // Only get data if value length <= this setting
// Multipage settings
var ew_PageIndex = 0;
var ew_MaxPageIndex = 0;
var ew_MinPageIndex = 0;
var EW_TABLE_CLASSNAME = "ewTable"; // Note: changed the class name as needed
var ew_MultiPageElements = new Array();
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ew61.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="userfn61.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Write your client script here, no need to add script tags.
// To include another .js script, use:
// ew_ClientScriptInclude("my_javascript.js");
//-->
</script>
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="1001" dir="rtl">
        <tr>
            <td width="995" colspan="2">
            <p align="center">
            <img border="0" src="Start.JPG" width="995" height="198"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#AC8601" width="737">
            <p align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#800000" width="254">
            <p align="center"><font size="5" color="#FFFFFF"><b>نتائج كلية 
            التجارة وإدارة الأعمال</b></font></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var EW_PAGE_ID = "list"; // Page id
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function ew_ValidateForm2(fobj) {
    var infix = "";
    for (var i=0;i<fobj.elements.length;i++) {
        var elem = fobj.elements[i];
        if (elem.name.substring(0,2) == "s_" || elem.name.substring(0,3) == "sv_")
            elem.value = "";
    }
    return true;
}
//-->
```

I am just asking for educational purposes, I want to make a project for my colleagues because the traffic in the website is very high and it takes hours to get even one result.
Thanks.

Comment: did you read the scrapy documentation? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html -> `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` - "Concurrency is the number of requests that are processed in parallel."

Comment: I just started learning yesterday, I am not asking how to do it I just wanted to know if it's possible to retrieve data from a website that gives data upon request

Comment: Learning includes research in the internet, for example on official documentation websites.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is purely used to parse and pull data from html. It in no way interacts with the browser or makes requests to servers, so no, BeautifulSoup will not help here.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you will be able to scrap all the results in one go using javascript, scrapy, BeautifulSoup, etc... if all the records are visible on the same page itself.

If the webpage displays results through pagination it should visit all the pages and scrap accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it's not visible on the same page it self nor it renders when you scroll.
It gives you the results of the specified Student ID, If you wish to see another result; refresh, type another ID, Hit search and it'll run the JavaScript code then retrieve the data.

Comment: then maybe this can help: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process and https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls

Comment: yes, what @jasie mentioned will be helpful in this scenario. To summarize for each student ID corresponding HTTP request should fetch the data that will be scrapped.